# How to create a new folder using react-native -fs

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, react-native-fs

How can I create a folder at the root of the internal storage in a React Native application, ensuring that the folder and its contents persist even if the app is uninstalled? I've explored the directory paths provided by react-native-fs, but none seem to fully meet my requirements. Ideally, I'd like to create a dedicated folder at the root level of the internal storage and save my files within it. Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this effectively?

Comment: On the root level is not possible. Use one of the existing public directories on root level to create your subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Console policies restrict access to the root of internal storage, and apps are encouraged to use other storage solutions like the app-specific directory provided by getFilesDir() method.

If you want to create a directory in the internal storage that persists across app installs and uninstalls, you can only use the app-specific directories provided by the Android system. Here's how you can do it in React Native:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const folderName = 'myPersistedFolder';

async function createPersistedFolder() {
  try {
    const filesDir = Platform.OS === 'android' ? RNFS. DownloadDirectoryPath : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
    const folderPath = `${filesDir}/${folderName}`;

    const folderExists = await RNFS.exists(folderPath);
    if (!folderExists) {
      RNFS.mkdir(folderPath)
            .then(() => {
              console.log('Folder created successfully');
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error('Error creating folder:', error);
            });
      console.log('Persisted folder created:', folderPath);
    } else {
      console.log('Persisted folder already exists:', folderPath);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating persisted folder:', error);
  }
}

createPersistedFolder();
```

Comment: Please tell full path of the directory. Then we know what you advise. This looks in root of external storage which will not go.

Comment: `await RNFS.mkdir(folderPath);` Why dont you check return value? An mkdir() might fail.

Comment: `you can only use the app-specific directories provided by the Android system. ` You mean: You should NOT use those app specific directories.

Comment: The following constants are available on the RNFS export:

**DocumentDirectoryPath** (String) The absolute path to the document directory

**DownloadDirectoryPath** (String) The absolute path to the download directory (on android only)

**LibraryDirectoryPath** (String) The absolute path to the NSLibraryDirectory (iOS only)

**ExternalDirectoryPath** (String) The absolute path to the external files, shared directory (android only)

**ExternalStorageDirectoryPath** (String) The absolute path to the external storage, shared directory (android only)

Comment: Yes they are constants. But what are the paths?  I asked for the value. "/strorage/emulated/0/DCIM ...." or whatever ? The one you used in your code.  ExternalDirectoryPath looks to me like "/storage/emulated/0" and you cannot create directories there...

Comment: @blackapps I didn't demonstrated here the exception handlings, the given solution is just for showing the way to write (create) files/folders in the storage. There can be multiple exceptions, which needs to be handled as per need.

Comment: ??? I did not talk about exceptions. I asked for a path.

Comment: Why you need the exact path? It is already described in the above comment where it will store. External storage means it is the root of your device's internal storage itself.

Comment: @blackapps my previous comment was the reply of your previous question where you asked: `Why dont you check return value? An mkdir() might fail.`

Comment: Need the path to be sure. And if it is /storage/emulated/0 your code will not work. But you do not seem to care.

Comment: mkdir() will not throw exceptions. It returns true or false.

Comment: ExternalDirectoryPath looks like app specific and it was asked for non app specific. I think you need to start with ExternalStorageDirectoryPath. Well tell full paths to be shure. I still dont know and it was all i asked for in my first comment. Sigh..

Comment: Yes you're correct actually. The specified path is the root level path that is /storage/emulated/0, where the write permission is not allowed at all. I also mentioned it in my answer, but somehow by mistake in the example code I wrote that path. Apology.
Preferably it should be **DownloadDirectoryPath** that will be inside the Downloads folder or ** DocumentDirectoryPath**

Comment: As far as mkDir() concerns, here you're wrong. It's not a bollean return, it always returns a promise, that need to be handled. Please verify @blackapps